# How to output newlines in textarea using Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to output a string that has \n from database into the textarea using the next :

```
  {!! Form::textarea('product_id', nl2br(e($order->product_id)), ['placeholder'=>'Enter product id', 'class'=>'form-control input-lg', 'rows'=>'3','required']) !!}
```

So if the string is `Cabbage - 2\r\nWater - 1\nBread - 2`

It should output:

```
Cabbage -2
Water - 1
Bread - 2
```

but instead it outputs exactly the mysql string without new lines.

Can anyone tell me where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Put your `\n`  between double quotes `"\n"` as opposed to having single quotes, `'\n'` or none at all.

Comment: as you can see in the code provided , there are no "" or '' , its simply an output from the db into a Form

Comment: put them please. Then try.